# Avoiding field prepopulation in a thymeleaf form with Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am having a trouble getting rid of the field prepopulation in a thymeleaf form and displaying text placeholders instead.

Here is the snippet of the form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/catch/save}" th:object="${catch}" method="post">

        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{species}" th:placeholder="Species"
            class="form-control mb-4 col-3"> 

        <input type="text" th:field="*{length}" th:placeholder="Length"
            class="form-control mb-4 col-3">

        <input type="text" th:field="*{weigth}" th:placeholder="Weigth"
            class="form-control mb-4 col-3">
```

and here is the image of the resulting form:

[Prepopulated form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAcvl.jpg)

My goal is to have the two fields prepopulated with "Length" and "Weigth". These fields correspond to **int** and **double** object fields, so if I understand correctly they are initiated with 0 when the bean is created and therefore so are th:fields when the form is loaded.

Could you help me find a way to solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't use primitives, use object wrappers `INteger` and `Double` instead.

Comment: Thank you, solves it. However, doesn't this approach (at least theoretically) potentially create performance issues as a result of autoboxing/unboxing?

Comment: Why would there be autoboxing here? The input is directly converted to an `Integer`. So not sure where autoboxing would come into play here.

Comment: Correct, my mistake. Thanks a lot!